# Sending route to Google Map via q attribute

Tags: google-maps

I have a link that opens Google Map with the q attribute like this example

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=a+to:+b+to:+c
```

The problem is that it doesn't work when people have accepted the newest version of Google Map, but it works with the old one.

Is there a way to force a version or a work around so that it works with both versions?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to make some directions up, and it seems like the format now is `https://www.google.com/maps/dir/a/b/c`

Comment: It works correctly with the new version, but with the old one it seems like the last caracter is not recognized...

Comment: I guess I can't get it to show the old version using that format.